# How we can display CodeIgniter session flash message in blade integrated view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, laravel-blade

I used
{{$this->session->flashdata('message')}} in a view say test.blade.php
after setting a session flash data  in controller 
but while redirecting  it result

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function flashdata() on null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using blade templating engine,you cannot print  flash data in your view,because when you are using balde, your view file is rendered into a separate file in some location (for eg: cache/ or etc)..so this time `$this` will not work on rendered view in  another location...so the if you need to print flash data,try below

```
@php
  $CI = &get_instance();
  echo $CI->session->flashdata("message");
@endphp
```

**Or** You can also use native php variable `$_SESSION`,which is an associative array containing session variables available

```
@php
   echo $_SESSION['message'];
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try autoloading codeigniter session library

application > config > autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Set config sessions something like with folder permission 0700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help                                                                                 Actually my codeIgniter session workes properly .But the problem is         I cant display messege as session flash data in view while integrating with blade template engine to CodeIgniter

Comment: @SANDEEPSS Echo it `<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>'

Comment: This wont work in blade where view name is something.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use flashdata with blade library, because blade library doesnt find $this. Try below code and let me know if it works.

1) Create a new model "flashdata_model.php"

```
<?php
class Flashdata_model extends CI_Model {

    // setter
    public function set($key, $msg){
        $_SESSION['flashdata']['_viewcount'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['flashdata'][$key] = $msg;
    }

    // getter (though we cant use this method in CI view)
    public function get($key){
        return $_SESSION['flashdata'][$key];
    }

    // clean
    public function clear(){
        // This will clear flashdata variable after using once 
        if($_SESSION['flashdata']['_viewcount'] == 1){
            unset($_SESSION['flashdata']);
        }
        else 
            $_SESSION['flashdata']['_viewcount'] = 1;

    }
}
```

2) whenever you want to use it in any controller call `clear` method in constructor to clear previous flash message.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller { 
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    // This will clear previous flash messages
    $this->flashdata_model->clear();
  }
}
```

3) To set flash message use

```
$this->flashdata_model->set("error", "Invalid username orpassword");
```

4) To print flash messages

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION["flashdata"]['error']))
    echo $_SESSION["flashdata"]['error'];

  if(isset($_SESSION["flashdata"]['msg']))
    echo $_SESSION["flashdata"]['msg'];
?>
```